# How do I get the user id from my database and display it using ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Here is my action method:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("{userId}")]
public IActionResult Show(int userId)
{
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> User = DbConnector.Query($"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = {userId}");
    ViewBag.userId = 1;
    return View();
}
```

And here is my `index.cshtml` file:

```
<h1>here is one user:</h1>
<h3>@ViewBag.userId</h3>
```

I think that I am doing something wrong in my controller but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Note that using string concatenation with inline SQL is risky and typically unnecessary. Depending on your provider, there should be a way to provide parameters. Also, it is generally bad form to use `SELECT *`. Otherwise, why are you using `ViewBag`? Why not using `return View(User);` and change your cshtml to have `@model List<Dictionary<string, object>>` at the top, then find your user id in the data. I'm not sure why you're using a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` to capture the results, but you'll need to provide example data of how that structure is filled if you want help with that.

Comment: @aquile hollins: Preferably to use [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping) (Object–relational mapping) technique and define your data model that might be passed to a view ([MVC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below.

Define your `User` data model:

```cs
public class User
{
    [Display(Name = "User Id")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    // Another properties ...
}
```

In the controller:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("{userId}")]
public IActionResult Show(int userId)
{
    User user = /* obtain the user record from the db */

    // Pass the user to the strongly typed view.
    return View(user);
}
```

In the `show.cshtml`:

```
@model Models.User

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="column">
        @Html.DisplayForModel()
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ohh ok that makes so much since! I forgot to define my model! You're a legend thanks.